# Replace content in all files inside s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replace

I have a s3 bucket which is mapped to a domian say xyz.com . When ever a user register on xyz.com a file is created and stored in s3 bucket. Now i have 1000 of files in s3 and I want to replace some text in those files. All files have common name in start ex abc-{rand}.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way of doing this would be to regenerate them again through the same process you originally used.

Personally I would try to avoid find and replace as it could lead to modifying parts that you did not intend.

Run multiple generations in parallel and **override** the existing files. This will ensure the files you generate will match your expectation and will not need to be modified again.

As a suggestion [enable versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-versioning.html) before any of these interactions if you want the ability to rollback quickly  in a scenario where it needs to be reverted.

Comment: I cant regnerate the files as it has some random id stored which is mapped to db.

Comment: Can you not get all these IDs from the DB and loop over? Alternatively you will need to download them all and programmatically replace the contents and then re upload

Comment: I would suggest if you have many files you do it programatically to avoid the time it might take manually. Build a script that can perform the find and replace.

Comment: can you please tell me how to download all files from s3. I can run a loop and replace that rand text

Comment: Via the CLI you would use the `aws s3 cp` command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: From the SDK you can use get_object too: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

Comment: No problem @MukulMunjal let me know if you have any problems :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217290/discussion-between-mukul-munjal-and-chris-williams).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't do this in place in S3. You have to **download** them, change their content and re-upload.

This is because S3 is an **object storage system**, not regular file system.

To simply working with S3 files, you can use third part tool [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). The tool will make the S3 appear like a filesystem on your os.

Comment: Any better way of doing because this will take lot of effort.

Comment: @MukulMunjal You can try using a third part tools, such as the one I added in the updated answer. But its still based on downloading and re-uploading files, but this time managed by the tool.

Comment: sure I will take a look over this and update here if i find something useful